# Efficiently assigning a name to a new variable based on a list of names in r

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of names `new.var.names <- c("a", "b", "c")`. And I have a dataframe DF - it doesn't matter what it contains - let's assume this:

```
StudyID <- c('sid124','sid66537','sid78848')
age <- c(87, 63, 45)
bmi <- c(24.3,19.2,23.5)
data <- data.frame(StudyID, age, bmi)
```

Now I want to add new variables and base their names on a list, `new.var.names`. I would do something like:

```
data$NewVar <- data$bmi/data$age
```

But I want to make multiple new variables, so naively I would create these like so:

```
data$a <- data$bmi/data$age
data$b <- data$bmi/data$age
data$c <- data$bmi/data$age
```

Obviously this is not efficient, as in the real world my list is rather long - hundreds of items. So I'd like to do something like:

```
for (v in new.var.names){
data$v <- data$bmi/data$age
}
```

But that wouldn't work - I've tried and somehow I knew it wouldn't hence the post :-P - as it creates the variable `v`, while I want to create the variables `a, b, c`. How do I get to that?

Thanks and best,

Sander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can just do this:

**Update: copying and pasting data from question to show it works**

```
StudyID <- c('sid124','sid66537','sid78848')
age <- c(87, 63, 45)
bmi <- c(24.3,19.2,23.5)
data <- data.frame(StudyID, age, bmi)

data$NewVar <- data$bmi/data$age

new.var.names <- c("a", "b", "c")

for (v in new.var.names){
  data[,c(v)] <- data$bmi/data$age
}
```

I don't see why you want to create three columns with exactly the same data, but you must have a reason for this?

Comment: Ah. Thanks. It doesn't work though. I'm getting the message: `Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , c(v), value = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  invalid subsetting` (I don't want to create exactly the same data, I just couldn't think of something else as an example for now...)

Comment: It should work without an error if you use the data from your own example, see update.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Well I tested your answer on the real data; that didn't work. Doesn't mean it wouldn't in other situations. In either case: both answers may also be useful for others. Great work!

Comment: Your answer @user3640617 also worked - just checked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I may have found the answer:

```
for (v in 1:length(new.var.names)){
  print(new.var.names[v]) # these are just for debugging/sanity check
  data[[ new.var.names[v] ]] <- data$bmi/data$age
  print(table(data[[ new.var.names[v] ]])) # these are just for debugging/sanity check
}
```

Awesome! Thanks for the help @user3640617